# How to dynamically use different existing database in django

Tags: mysql, django, orm, backend

i have around ten to twenty databases with same structure in mysql, 
and how can i load those database dynamically in django?
(there will be a table storing those databases name, which may add/delete during the programme)

edit:
the **dynamically** way means that while running my website, create the orm and do somethings of another database by data input by users or which stored in the database

those database are:
1)with the same structure 
2)only the name of database is different
3)not define in my setting.py when the web is started

Comment: Perhaps you should clarify what you mean by "loading the databases dynamically"?

Answer (score -1):

Django has a built-in feature to support multiple databases check it out here https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/db/multi-db/#multiple-databases